# Using GPUImage GPUImageMovieWriter or GPUImageBuffer to create Slow Motion Video

Tags: swift, avfoundation, gpuimage

Looking into this there is no straightforward way to use GPUImage to create slow motion video as mentioned here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/709

Though according to this: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1641 Brad Larson states that there could be a way using GPUImageBuffer to create a slow motion version of a video.

Has anyone been able to make this happen or been able to use AVFoundation to make it happen with a video created using GPUImage?

Swift code would be most appreciated though Objective C could be helpful. Thanks for your superior aid.